# Constrain the height of RelativeLayout to specific child view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I there a way to `wrap_content` on a specific element inside of a parent element? For instance, I have something like the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout width:match height:wrap>
  <ImageView width:match height:wrap scale:fitXY />
  <LinearLayout width:wrap height:wrap>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The parent wrap constraint is very loose, but I want it to specifically use the matching width, but always match the height of the image view.

The problem here arises when I place this view in another RelativeLayout where each view is aligned above or below another in order to fill a potentially changing superview.  LinearLayout didn't really seem to stretch things to fill, so I switched to Relative, but when I did, the view described above stretched vertically when I want it to still match the height of the image view.

Is there a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the following (pseudocode) in the onResume() method:

```
if(myRelativeLayout.height > myImageView.height)
    myRelativeLayout.setHeight(myImageView.height);
```

You need to make sure to call `myRelativeLayout.measure()` before you do this, so the system knows what the size of the `View`s will be.

Just an idea for you to try, let me know if it works :)

Comment: Since this is a self-contained compound component, I would probably want to put this in `onLayout()`.  However, there does not appear to be a `setHeight()` method on `RelativeLayout`.  I did try overriding `onMeasure()` and using `setMeasuredDimension(this.getMeasuredWidth, this.subview.getMeasuredHeight()` and a number of other variations on this, but none of them work. Either it does nothing or the whole view disappears.